# Space between ICON and TEXT in Tab control - Android

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am using compact tab for my app.

```
    TabHelper tabHelper = getTabHelper();

    CompatTab menuTab = tabHelper.newTab("menu");
    menuTab.setText(R.string.tab_section1);

    menuTab.setIcon(R.drawable.home_icon);
    menuTab.setTabListener(new InstantiatingTabListener(
            this, MenuFragment.class));
    tabHelper.addTab(menuTab);
```

I do have resource file code as follow

```
    <string name="tab_section1">Home</string>
```

Menu Tab renders properly but there is no SPACE between ICON and TEXT. How can I achieve it?

[image: Icon and text "Map" is very close without space]

Icon and text "Map" is very close without space

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" 
 android:drawable="@drawable/home_selected" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/home" />
</selector>
```

My setText Methos

```
@Override
public CompatTab setText(int resId) {
    mText = mActivity.getResources().getText(resId);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add space in String?

Comment: try to **set margin** for it.

Comment: Edited my post.how can set margin for selector?

Comment: adding space to string not allowed in xml abhilash

Comment: @iShare: I think I can use space in String,<string name="stringname">           Home</string>

Answer (score 5):

Try this, :)

```
menuTab.setText("\t"+"Home");
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the size of width of home_icon image.